# check number of a given character occurence in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to write a simple class to process Strings (may be very long strings up to 1mil characters in it).  String will basically consists of two characters "a" and "b" that may be intermingled with each other.  If the number of a's equal number of b's then app will say it is OK otherwise NOK.  I wonder how to do that most efficiently.  I thought of using regex to split String and then count occurence of a's and b's but maybe someone knows better way to do that.  Am relatively new to regex so please let me know should there be any bugs.  This is my early attempt.

```
public class Typo { 
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        String ver = "";
        int na = 0;
        int nb = 0;
        String regex = ("\\w.+");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String text = "ababababbaba";
        if (text.length() == 0){
            ver = "OK";
        }
        else if (text.length() == 1){
            ver = "NOK";
        }
        else if ((text.length() % 2) == 1){
            ver = "NOK";
        }
        else if ((text.length() % 2) == 0){
            //check number of a and b and if it equals return OK otherwise NOK
            Matcher m1 = p.matcher("a");
            while(m1.find()){
                na = na + 1;
            }
            Matcher m2 = p.matcher("b");
            while(m2.find()){
                nb = nb + 1;
            }
            if (na == nb){
                ver = "OK";
            }
            else 
                ver = "NOK";
        }
        System.out.println(ver);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just loop over the characters and count the number of each? I find it impossible to believe that using regular expressions would be faster--but this is trivial to benchmark. Have you?

Comment: currently I have a problem with String such as "abbb" as they return ok while they shouldn't.  And also optimization problems for very long strings.

Comment: @ Dave I'm not sure as far as performance is concerned what is faster.  I thought that for v.long string regex could be faster, but am not sure.  How would you suggest to perform such iteration on my string?

Comment: Define "optimization problems". Prove to me using regular expressions is faster than simply counting--they might be, but I don't see how yet, which is why I'm asking you to show me.

Comment: How to perform such iteration? With a `for` loop.

Comment: Hi Dave, still struggling to do it with for loop can you provide solution?

Comment: What have you tried? It's significantly more straight-forward than your existing solution; I don't see how you could have written the above but not be able to iterate over a string.

Comment: Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: ok managed this.  No it is not a homework.

Comment: You're lucky other people are more willing to spoon-feed than I am. It's too bad--this would have been a good learning experience.

Comment: mainly for exercise.  why do you suspect everything is a homework?  If it would be I would mark it as such for sure;)

Comment: well according to my knowledge homework is something that a teacher or lecturer asks you to do after a your class/lecture (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/homework?q=homework).  I wasn't ordered by anyone to do this exercise = it is not a homework.  Please learn some basic english vocabulary before arguing;)  And well I used "everything" too stress since you were not believing my first answer.  btw.  am quite new to stackoverflow so did not that there was a need to mark anything as homework either.

Comment: (Note that two of your questions have been tagged with "homework", because the questions you are asking look identical to homework. Even if they're not school-assigned [homework](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homework), wouldn't you rather be given hints and ideas rather than outright answers? If the goal is self-study, why wouldn't you treat it the same way you would treat [homework](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homework)?)

Comment: Well I was asking here for ideas mainly, sometimes also for some solutions to speed up my work (so that I can focus on different things).  But once I asked I actually have done it myself too if u havent noticed. I have asked quite a lot of questions and these two are small percentage of total questions.  None of the definitions (also one provided by you) matches what I was doing since I wasn't preparing for any event either.

Comment: You're preparing to know Java. You're studying the language and its techniques. How you approach that is up to you--I don't *understand* your approach, but that doesn't make it wrong, I just don't think it's effective long-term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need regular expression and split the string for this! You can simply loop through the string and count the number of a and bs. You need to keep two different counter, one for a and one for b. Using regular expression will be less efficient. There is no way you can get the result without traversing the string at least once. So use a simple loop to count a and b.

- You can make one optimization in the loop. If anytime mod of `countA - countB` is greater than the number of remaining characters then a and b can never be equal. So you can break the loop then.
- If the length of the string is odd then there is no need to count. Count of a and b can never be equal when total number of elements is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not using regexp for this problem: generally speaking, regexp is not good when you need to count anything. You cannot even write a regexp to check if brackets in an expression are balanced.

For this problem a simple counter will be sufficient: increment on `a`, decrement on `b`, check for zero in the end to know the answer to your problem.

```
boolean check(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != s.length() ; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            count++;
        } else { /* it is b */
            count--;
        }
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
private static boolean check(String input) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count == input.length() >> 1; // count == input.length()/2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use a third party library like [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html). It has a method [countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which will do the work.

```
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "a")   = 2
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "ab")  = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using something simple as this? Your idea of doing something as simple as this is an overkill, and would end up using more resources.

```
String s = "abbb";

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
    if((s.charAt(i) == 'a')){
        a += 1;
    } else {
        b += 1;
    }
}
```

`a = 1; b = 3`

Comment: well wanted to try sth new such as regex and thought this would make things quicker, but well it seems not.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Typo { 
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        String ver = "NOK";

        String text = "ababababbaba";

        if( (text.length() - text.replaceAll("a","").length() ) ==  
            ( text.length() - text.replaceAll("b","").length() ) ) {
            ver = "OK";     
        }

        System.out.println(ver);
    }
}
```