# Character Occurrence

Tags: java, string, ascii, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check number of a given character occurence in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055959/check-number-of-a-given-character-occurence-in-a-string)

I'm trying to make a program that checks how many times a character occurs in a string. 
I managed to convert it to ASCII but I also want to be able to count how many time a certain character or an ASCII value appears in the string.

```
   String myString = "Hello.";
    for (int i=0;i<myString.length();i++){
char c = myString.charAt(i);
int j = (int) c;
System.out.println("ASCII OF "+c +" = " + j + ".");
    }
```

If you have any other alternative apart from converting to ASCII, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
String myString = "Hello.";
char searchChar = 'l';
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    char c = myString.charAt(i);
    if (c == searchChar) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println(count);
```

This could easily be turned into a method to use many times:

```
/**
 * Return the number of occurences of a character in the specified String.
 * 
 * @param string the string to search
 * @param searchChar the char to search for
 * @return the number of occurences of searchChar in string
 */
public int countChars(String string, char searchChar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c == searchChar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```